# Order of columns after pivot in application insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

User wants a count of unique sessions per week in application insights.  I have the query working, including a pivot, but the Week columns are out of order.  I would prefer if they were in order.

```
pageViews
| where timestamp < now() 
| summarize Sessions= dcount(session_Id)
  by Week=bin(datepart("weekOfYear", timestamp), 1), user_AuthenticatedId
| order by Week
| evaluate pivot(Week, sum(Sessions))
| join kind=innerunique (pageViews
                      | summarize MostRecentRequest =    max(timestamp)  by user_AuthenticatedId) 
                      on $right.user_AuthenticatedId == $left.user_AuthenticatedId
| project-away user_AuthenticatedId1
```

I've tried ordering by timestamp before the summarize, and ordering by week after the summarize (still in there) and no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently a "trick" that will work: `serialize` right after your `order by`

```
pageViews
| where timestamp < now()
| where isnotempty(user_AuthenticatedId)
| summarize Sessions= dcount(session_Id)
  by Week=bin(datepart("weekOfYear", timestamp), 1), user_AuthenticatedId
| order by Week
| serialize // <--------------------------------- RIGHT HERE
| evaluate pivot(Week, sum(Sessions))
| join kind=innerunique (pageViews
| summarize TotalSessions=dcount(session_Id), MostRecentRequest = max(timestamp) by user_AuthenticatedId) 
on $right.user_AuthenticatedId == $left.user_AuthenticatedId
| project-away user_AuthenticatedId1
| top 100 by TotalSessions desc
```

gets me this in workbooks, with the weeks in descending order (I also added total session count to sort/top by with some custom column settings set):

[image: workbook with heatmap]

the custom settings I have for the column settings in workbooks:
delete all the #'d columns that are there by default and add one for `^[0-9]+$` set to heatmap:
[image: column settings]

Answer (score 0):

I refactored query a bit for my own comprehension. I took the the left and right into "views". Thought I'd share.

```
let users_MostRecent_Session = 
    pageViews
    | summarize 
        TotalSessions=dcount(session_Id)
        , MostRecentRequest = max(timestamp)  
        by 
        user_AuthenticatedId
;
//
let users_sessions_ByWeek = 
    pageViews
    | where timestamp < now() 
    | where isnotempty(user_AuthenticatedId)
    | summarize 
        Sessions= dcount(session_Id)
        by 
        Week=bin(datepart("weekOfYear", timestamp), 1)
        , user_AuthenticatedId
    | order by Week
    | serialize 
    | evaluate pivot(Week, sum(Sessions))
;
//
//
users_sessions_ByWeek
| join  kind=innerunique 
        users_MostRecent_Session 
        on user_AuthenticatedId
| project-away user_AuthenticatedId1
| top 100 by TotalSessions desc
```